# Entity Framework, problems making primary key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I ran an email scraper and put all the emails into a file that's to be put into a database for my class (they won't be used for anything, just for the sake of assignment), I'm just having a little trouble putting them into the database properly. Right now I have a file of 1000 emails, their URL's, and the domain names (I put it to a file because it took a long time to collect all the emails and I let it run over a couple of nights).

The file lists as email, url, domain, email, url etc... So I read the whole file into a queue and then insert them into the DB like this:

```
public class Source
{
    [Key]
    public int SourceId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    // Nav Prop
    public virtual List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class Email // POCO
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    // Nav Prop
    public virtual Source Source { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new ScraperContext())
{
    while (emailArrayQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        db.Emails.Add(new Email()
                {
                    EmailAddress = (string)emailArrayQueue.Dequeue(),
                    Url = (string)emailArrayQueue.Dequeue(),
                    CreationTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Source = new Source()
                    {
                        SourceId = emailArrayQueue.Peek().GetHashCode(),//line that doesn't work
                        Domain = (string)emailArrayQueue.Dequeue()
                    }
                });

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Due to the nature of how I'm trying to work this, I thought this would be the best way to get them into the database, but the highlighted line doesn't seem to work as every source ID seems to just default to the number at which it was created. Meaning that there are both 1000 sources and 1000 emails in the DB. I'm trying to make the domain names the primary key so there are far fewer domain names than emails.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code doesn't really make a lot of sense, but I'll brake it down to you.

This will not work since it dequeues 2 items:

```
EmailAddress = (string)emailArrayQueue.Dequeue(),
Url = (string)emailArrayQueue.Dequeue()
```

Unless your email queue has emailAddresses, urls (Whatever that means), and domain (Part of email address?) all combined which is not a problem, more like a design flaw, or maybe that's where you get your data from, idk.

Now your actual question:

When you insert the "Source" in the database a new key is assigned to it (Unless otherwise specified), you can go through a lot a trouble and try to make it so you can insert keys OR, you can do one of the following:

1. Keep track of sources:
   Whenever you create a source you first check if it wasn't previously created, if it was use that instance, if it wasn't then you create a new one.
   You can use a Dictionary or something like that to do this. Do this if you have a long list of emails.
2. Create a list of sources, then addrange.
   This method is easier if you don't have a lot emails.
   Keep a list of sources, for every email add it to the list of emails from the source (Create a source if there isn't one yet).
   At the end AddRange all your sources.

Hope it helps